# Вопрос по коммитам в Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

Есть ли в `Visual Studio Code` что-то наподобие окна `Commit Changes` в `WebStorm` (на скрине), который вызывается горячими клавишами `Ctrl+K`?

Если нет, подскажите, может есть какой-нибудь плагин для не менее удобного просмотра изменений файлов и коммитов

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть. Вот вкладка:
[image: ь]
Там можно просмотреть изменения и отправить коммит.